# Python CSV Nested For Loop String Replacement

Tags: csv, python-3.x, for-loop, nested, str-replace

I'm trying to say: for each of the `campaigns[0]`  (ie: `"New York City", "DC", "New York", "Boston", "Detroit", "St. Louis", "Cleveland"`), THEN for each `row[2]` within a CSV, replace `[city_name], [state_abbrev], [state_full]` with `campaigns[1], campaigns[2], campaigns[3]`.

```
import csv

campaigns = [
            ["New York City", "New York City", "New York", "NY"],
            ["DC", "Washington DC", "Washington DC", "DC"],
            ["New York", "New York", "New York", "NY"],
            ["Boston", "Boston", "Massachusetts", "MA"],
            ["Detroit", "Detroit", "Michigan", "MI"],
            ["St. Louis", "St Louis", "Missouri", "MO"],
            ["Cleveland", "Cleveland", "Ohio", "OH"]
            ]

with open('ExpandCampaign.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  print(next(reader, None))  # Print the header
  for campaign in campaigns:
    for row in reader:
      row[0] = campaign[0]
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[city_name]', campaign[1].lower())
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[state_full]', campaign[2].lower())
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[state_abbrev]', campaign[3].lower())
      print(row)
```

Problem: The code above is only outputting New York City but not the other campaign names in campaigns[0].

```
['New York City', 'Design', 'basement design', 'Exact']
['New York City', 'Floor Plans', 'basement design plans', 'Exact']
['New York City', 'Design', 'basement designs', 'Exact']
['New York City', 'Finishing', 'basement finished remodeling', 'Exact']
['New York City', 'Finishing', 'basement finishers ny', 'Exact']
['New York City', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing', 'Exact']
['New York City', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing new york city', 'Exact']
```

I don't understand why it's not iterating through each `campaign[0]` name and it's only seeing New York City.  For example, if I print:

```
with open('ExpandCampaign.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  print(next(reader, None))  # Print the header
  for campaign in campaigns:
    print(campaign[0])
```

I get:

```
['Campaign', 'Ad Group', 'Keyword', 'Type']
New York City
DC
New York
Boston
Detroit
St. Louis
Cleveland
```

I've tried to switch around the for statements but what I get is results like this:

```
['New York City', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing in new york city ny', 'Phrase']
['DC', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing in new york city ny', 'Phrase']
['New York', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing in new york city ny', 'Phrase']
['Boston', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing in new york city ny', 'Phrase']
['Detroit', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing in new york city ny', 'Phrase']
['St. Louis', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing in new york city ny', 'Phrase']
['Cleveland', 'Finishing', 'basement finishing in new york city ny', 'Phrase']
```

See how "new york city" is appearing for non-New York City campaigns?  That's something I don't want to happen because these cities are only relevant to their respective campaigns and not each other.  My logic in how to solve this is obviously off somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through all the rows in the first pass of the "for campaign" loop.  Add print statements like in the following snippet and you'll see:

```
  for campaign in campaigns:
    print(campaign) # add this line
    for row in reader:
      row[0] = campaign[0]
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[city_name]', campaign[1].lower())
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[state_full]', campaign[2].lower())
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[state_abbrev]', campaign[3].lower())
      print(row)
```

Maybe you just want one loop for both the campaign and the rows like the following

```
for (campaign,row) in zip(campaigns, reader):
      row[0] = campaign[0]
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[city_name]', campaign[1].lower())
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[state_full]', campaign[2].lower())
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[state_abbrev]', campaign[3].lower())
      print(row)
```

It will terminate on the shorter of the two lists.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using `csv.reader` and instead read the file without it and it works.  I don't know why this works and the `csv.reader` approach didn't.

```
campaigns = [
            ["New York City", "New York City", "New York", "NY"],
            ["DC", "Washington DC", "Washington DC", "DC"],
            ["New York", "New York", "New York", "NY"],
            ["Boston", "Boston", "Massachusetts", "MA"],
            ["Detroit", "Detroit", "Michigan", "MI"],
            ["St. Louis", "St Louis", "Missouri", "MO"],
            ["Cleveland", "Cleveland", "Ohio", "OH"]
            ]

with open('ExpandCampaign.csv', 'r') as f:
  print(next(f, None).strip().split(','))  # Print the header
  rows = [row.strip().split(',') for row in f]
  for campaign in campaigns:
    for row in rows:
      row[0] = campaign[0]
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[city_name]', campaign[1].lower())
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[state_full]', campaign[2].lower())
      row[2] = row[2].replace('[state_abbrev]', campaign[3].lower())
      print(row)
```